# MPAndroid adjustment to screen size without fixed height

Tags: android, xml, layout, mpandroidchart

So I have been trying every mix and match with different layouts and settings and still cant figure out how to make this work. I want to have a spinner on the Same Screen as an MPAndroid Line Chart, I know I can fix the height Manually and adjust it to fit properly, but fill parent or match parent does not account for the spinner and just pushes it off the screen! If I load the application on my phone with height of 290dp Great fits perfectly! Load it on the 7" tablet not so pretty... Half the screen is empty. How do I contain the Chart to fill a layout that accounts for spinner? Wrap Content on the chart makes it unusable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".history"
    android:background="#303030">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:entries="@array/list3"
    android:popupBackground="#303030"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context=".history"
 android:background="#303030">

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="70">
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="30"
android:id="@+id/spinner4"
android:entries="@array/list3"
android:popupBackground="#303030"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Because of using weight, on any screen "map and spinner" will look like in same screen height ratio.

Comment: android:layout_weight="" That is an awesome Tool! That will serve me greatly in future!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try using this I have removed some attributes which were missing at my end. This is where spinner is on top and rest is filled with line chart.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:popupBackground="#303030" />

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was hoping to have the spinner on the bottom, but I appreciate the Input, I'm actually getting a look at the code now just to get a better understanding as to why it works :)

Comment: for aligning spinner to bottom. just add 
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to spinner and add
`android:layout_above="@+id/spinner4"` to linechart. 
answer from @User_1191 is using linearlayout is also valid.